# Custom Report Types missing related Object

Tags: reporting, custom-object, custom-report-type

**Background**

I have 3 custom objects:

1. `Invoice__c`
2. `Invoice_Line__c`
3. `Appointment__c`

Their relationships are:

1. `Invoice__c` is a parent (master-detail) to `Invoice_Line__c`
2. `Invoice_Line__c` has a lookup to `Appointment__c`

**Question**

Why can't I create a custom Report Type linking the 3 objects together?

i.e.

`Appointment__c` > `Invoice_Line__c` > `Invoice__c`

Or some other combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start from the common child object (invoice line), then you can go "up" to both parents. These fields are not shown in the palette by default, but you can add them using the "add via relationship" function found there.

[image: Add fields related via lookup]